# Make URL language-specific (via routes)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing, globalization

Its hard to find an answer to this specific question, so ill pop it up here:

We want to build up our urls completely language specific, meaning

> www.mysite.com/EN
>
> www.mysite.com/DE

this is done in the RouteConfig with

```
url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

But then the tricky part:

> www.mysite.com/EN/Categories
>
> www.mysite.com/DE/Kategorien

I.e. make the controllername appear in a multiple languages, but point to the same controller. Is this even possible?

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087) for a complete solution.

Comment: I would use URL rewriting for this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, this is partially possible (the language part only). The controller name in a different language is definitely an interesting point, but I think it would be hard to achieve that. Think about what it would look like for Bidi languages like Arabic and Hebrew. It would probably be a good idea to use controller in different languages but you would create a havoc for yourself and I believe that you would have to change the underlying MVC structure to allow for this.

The language changing part is easy and could be done like below.

What you might want to look at is the globalization. Basically the language part corresponds to the current threads UI culture. What you need is the following:

1. Define a route, something like this:

   ```
   var lang = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { language = lang, controller = "Home", 
                       action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
   ```
2. Register `Application_AcquireRequestState` and define it something like this:

   ```
   protected void Application_AcquireRequestState()
   {
       var routes = RouteTable.Routes;

       var httpContext = Request.RequestContext.HttpContext;
       if (httpContext == null) return;

       var routeData = routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

       var language = routeData.Values["language"] as string;
       var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);

       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
   }
   ```

   Although `CurrentUICulture` is what you need switch languages load information from a resource file, you should also change the `CurrentCulture` to the same `CultureInfo`;
3. Last, make sure you have corresponding resource files and a fallback resource file.

I used `Name` property of `CultureInfo` so you German would be de-DE, English en-US, etc. 
This should do the trick.

In case you need more information I could upload a sample MVC project for you to examine.

UPDATE: One crude way of doing what you want is to invert the order of route segments to something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewDefault",
    url: "{language}/{id}/{action}/{controller}",
    defaults: new { language = lang, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "Category"}
);
```

This way you could make a following request http://www.your_url.com/de/Kategorien. In this case Kategorien maps to the `id` rather than a controller. You controller stays in English or German (depending how you named it) but user sees a different language. In the background your view might be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string categoryName)
{
    // Fetch data based on category name (categoryName)
    return View();
}
```

You could pass additional information as parameters, but you will need to adjust your route to look something like: {language}/{category}/{subcategory}/{action}/{controller}

Just know that this can become pain in the neck in the long run and if you try this, then make sure you document it well.

Comment: Hi Husein,

Thanks for your reply. That language implementation looks good, i will implement it like that. But the real (tricky) problem is the diferentiation between 5 different languages áfter that. 

/EN/Categories
/NL/Categorieen
/DE/Kategorien
/FR/Catégories
PL/Kategorie

...should all point to the same controller. Im not sure if that is even possible, maybe only with constraints for these 5 textstrings...

Comment: I've updated my answer with an idea that occurred to me. Hope it helps.

Comment: hi Ron, just a heads up that i eventually implemented more or less your updated answer, making the categories a variable.


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "CategoryOverview",
                url: "{language}/{category}",
                defaults: new { language = lang, controller = "Categories", action = "Index" }
            );

Comment: Great, @stefjnl, I hope I helped you. Regards!

Comment: Hey I'm getting error when typing strange language in url, can you update post to handle that, redirect to error controller with message or someting.

Comment: @SenadMeškin, in order to handle errors you can setup custom error redirection in your web.config. If you are calling an action on controller which does not exist then you should override `HandleUnknowAction` on that controller to prevent yellow screen of death.

Comment: How do I register `Application_AcquireRequestState`?